# Linq Method Error IOrderedQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a database with a specific id with recorded Time's, I need help on trying to figure out time gap's between an ID's time's e.g 13:05:15 and 13:05:45 though if the time gap is over 10/15 seconds it needs to be recorded so it can be used in say a text file/other data etc. I previously asked a similar question on here, here is what my code looks like so far:

This class is used to manipulate data through the linq var being queried/looped

```
public class Result
{
    public bool LongerThan10Seconds { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime CompletionTime { get; set; }
}
```

This is the foor loop within a separate class which was my original idea

```
using (var data = new ProjectEntities())
{
    Result lastResult = null;
    List<Result> dataResults = new List<Result>();

    foreach(var subResult in data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().Select(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.Time)))
    {
        if (lastResult != null)
        {
            if (subResult.CompletionTime.Subtract(lastResult.CompletionTime).Seconds > 10)
                dataResults.Add(subResult);
        }
        lastResult = subResult;
    }
```

Which I got the error:

```
 Linq.IOrderedQueryAble does not contain a definition for 'CompletionTime' and no Extension method 'CompletionTime' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IOrderedQueryable.
```

I changed the for loop to use an object of the manipulation class

```
foreach(Result subResult in data.AssetStatusHistories.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct().SelectMany(Id => data.AssetStatusHistories.Where(x => x.ID == Id).OrderBy(x => x.TimeStamp)))
{
    if (lastResult != null)
    {
        if (subResult.CompletionTime.Subtract(lastResult.CompletionTime).Seconds > 10)
        {
            vehicleResults.Add(subResult);
        }                
    }

    lastResult = subResult;
}
```

Though now I get the error: `Cannot convert type 'Project.Status' to 'Project.Result'`

Does anyone possibly have a solution to get around this I have looked through a few resources but haven't been able to find anything of helps also even on Microsoft's Linq Forum. Any help is much appreciated ! :)

Comment: Please add note of on which line the exception occurs

Comment: Instead of replacing your question with the text "solved", please accept an answer. If no answers are appropriate you can add your own answer to the question and accept that.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `.ToList()` to the end of your LINQ statement, after `OrderBy`:

```
var results = data.Status.Select(x => x.ID).Distinct()
                         .Select(Id => data.Status.Where(x => x.ID == Id)
                                                  .OrderBy(x => x.Time)
                                                  .ToList();

foreach(var subResult in results))
{
    ...
}
```

Also, I think you could modify your LINQ to do a `GroupBy` of the `ID` column, but that's something you could do research on if you wish. ([Tutorial](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/LINQ-to-DataSets-Grouping-c62703ea))

Comment: Hi this works though within the for loop i am getting the same problem when I want to use my class method: if (subResult.CompletionTime.Subtract(lastResult.CompletionTime).Seconds > 10) the error occurs on subResult.CompletionTime which I get the Systems.Collections.Generic.List Error again

Answer (score 0):

Your linq query (in the second try) will return an IEnumerable of whatever is the element type of `data.AssetStatusHistories`.  I assume this is some kind of `IEnumerable<Project.Status>`, so you're in fact trying to assign `Project.Status` objects to an iterator variable (subResult) of type `Result`, which is why you're getting the error `Cannot convert type 'Project.Status' to 'Project.Result'`.

So your problem is not really in the linq query, you just need a way to convert your `Project.Status` objects to `Project.Result` objects.